# VS 2010 Crystal Report application only returning data for first generated report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have in front of me a Crystal Reports project that I just started looking at. It was first done in Visual Studio 2005 and is now being converted to Visual Studio 2010. 2005 used merge modules and the approach is a bit different in 2010 as I have understood it.

After some fiddling around I got it to compile and the installer to package the application. Everything seemed to work fine but then I notice that I only get the report populated with data for the first report I generate. After that they all come up empty. I have to restart the application to get data in the reports again.
The application is using the [Crystal Reports Helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15024/Crystal-Reports-helper-class) from Code Project which handles binding of data etc.

Anyone used this class or know if it could be something in Crystal Reports itself that is causing this problem? The application is using the *Crystal Report Viewer* control.

Comment: Instead of restarting the application, try refreshing the report using refresh icon in the Crystal Report Viewer. Tell me whether you are getting records after refreshing the report.

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan The refresh button was initialy hidden. But enabling it and clicking on it I'm presented with controls for selecting date range. Upon doing so (selected same date as I just created a report for) and clicking ok I presented with a populated report like the initial one.

Comment: are u sure that ur report is working fine in Crystal Report Tool? You need to comfirm that your report generates correct records and runs fine in Crystal Report Tool

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be any problems using Crystal Reports own tools. The reports were initially created using CR 10 and the application was made using VS 2005. So I'm wondering if there might be some compatibility issues with the new CR runtimes and the reports or the conversion from VS 2005 to 2010.

Comment: Even i too faced this kinda problem !
After passing parameter thru windows controls, i ll run the report. 1st record will be fetched. When I change the parameter and run again, report will be empty. But if i press refresh button in the report viewer, i ll get the correct records.

Comment: Have u wrote `crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();` to refresh your report viewer??

Comment: When generating a second report a *Disconnect* function is beeing run. Looking at that it that function it runs and sets the following on the Crystal Reports Helper Class: *Close()*, *DataSource = null*, *ReportSource = null* and also sets *ReportSource = 0* on the Report Viewer control.

Comment: so you are supposed to fix that, I hope there are no issues with your crystal report file. You need to check with your coding part...

Comment: I'll let you know what I find. This is an old legacy application so there is probably tons of strange stuff going on.